# How to move a ProjectName.vdproj to a different directory?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-deployment, vdproj

I have a setup project which I would like to move to a different directory. I have found a way to change where the MSI files will go to, but I'm struggling to find a way to move vdproj files.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move Vdproj files, but you have to correct all SourcePath tags inside the project file. The path there is usually relative, so you have to know the new relative path. Other than that, I don't see a problem.